# convert odex file to dex file

Tags: android, dex, smali

I would like to covert odex file to dex file. I already pulled framework folder from system. I tried the following command,

```
java -jar baksmali-2.1.2.jar -d system/framework -x temp.odex
```

but error was produced - error message is like below.

```
 Error occurred while loading boot class path files. Aborting. org.jf.util.ExceptionWithContext: Cannot locate boot class path file /system/framework/core.jar
        at org.jf.dexlib2.analysis.ClassPath.loadClassPathEntry(ClassPath.java:277)
        at org.jf.dexlib2.analysis.ClassPath.fromClassPath(ClassPath.java:182)
        at org.jf.baksmali.baksmali.disassembleDexFile(baksmali.java:67)
        at org.jf.baksmali.main.run(main.java:113)
        at org.jf.baksmali.main.main(main.java:322)
```

I could not find "core.jar" in my android system framework folder.

Comment: Is this with dalvik? Or art?

Answer (score 5):

As of 2017-06-09 baksmali has changed. It works like this.

```
java -jar baksmali-2.2.0.jar d SamsungInCallUI.odex -o SamsungInCallUI
```

Then assemble the dex file.

```
java -jar smali-2.2.0.jar ass SamsungInCallUI -o SamsungInCallUI.dex
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
java -jar baksmali-2.1.2.jar -c boot.oat -d system/framework/arm/boot.oat -x temp.odex
```

The specific path to your boot.oat might be different.

Also note that baksmali doesn't yet support deodexing the N preview images.

Comment: I tried it but another error was produced.  Error occurred while loading boot class path files. Aborting.
org.jf.util.ExceptionWithContext: Cannot locate boot class path file boot.oat
        at org.jf.dexlib2.analysis.ClassPath.loadClassPathEntry(ClassPath.java:2
77)
        at org.jf.dexlib2.analysis.ClassPath.fromClassPath(ClassPath.java:182)
        at org.jf.baksmali.baksmali.disassembleDexFile(baksmali.java:67)
        at org.jf.baksmali.main.run(main.java:113)
        at org.jf.baksmali.main.main(main.java:322)

Comment: Like I said, the specific path to your boot.oat might be different.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me `adb pull /system/framework/arm/boot.oat /tmp/framework/boot.oat` Placing the apk and the odex file `baksmali.jar -x -c boot.oat -d /tmp/framework APKname.odex -o APKname`

Comment: I tried like this. java -jar baksmali-2.1.2.j
ar -x -c boot.oat -d system/framework Test.odex -o Test.apk. but error was produced. Error occurred while loading boot class path files. Aborting. org.jf.util.ExceptionWithContext: Cannot locate boot class path file boot.oat at org.jf.dexlib2.analysis.ClassPath.loadClassPathEntry(ClassPath.java:2 77) at org.jf.dexlib2.analysis.ClassPath.fromClassPath(ClassPath.java:182) at org.jf.baksmali.baksmali.disassembleDexFile(baksmali.java:67) at org.jf.baksmali.main.run(main.java:113) at org.jf.baksmali.main.main(main.java:322)

Comment: Make sure the file boot.oat is in system/framework this should be the code

`java -jar baksmali-2.1.2.jar -x -c boot.oat -d system/framework temp.odex -o temp`

Comment: I pulled boot.oat from system/framework and retry it. but same error was reproduced.

Comment: `system/framework` is just the path of boot.oat on your PC, if you just pulled system/framework without moving boot.oat then the path would be `system/framework/arm`, you have to make sure this path leads to boot.oat on YOUR PC. Try this code 
`java -jar baksmali-2.1.2.jar -x -c boot.oat -d system/framework/arm temp.odex -o temp`

Comment: Thank you. I successed it for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I've understood correctly your question (kindly correct me if I'm wrong), but if you are trying to convert an odex to dex, I've already replied to a similar question here: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12393/reverse-engineering-android-vendor-system-apps/12406#12406

Anyway, to my knowledge you have two chooice:

- Follow this guide: http://www.naldotech.com/how-to-deodex-applications-on-android-5-0-lollipop/
- Or use `oat2dex` as pointed out by the user who commented my answer on RE stackexchange.

Good luck

Comment: I tried this with oat2dex. but erro was produced. error message is "OAT Hader Checking..: FAIL! OAT2DEX File Check File FAIL".

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of @kakopappa's answer.

Get the latest version of baksmali and smali jar from [here](https://bitbucket.org/JesusFreke/smali/downloads/) and put them in a folder and add this method to your .bash_profile file if you are a mac/linux user.

Get baksmali and smali jar in your computer and assign it to these variables from terminal.

> BAKSMALI_JAR_PATH = ""
>
> SMALI_JAR_PATH=""

Note : After editing the value should look something like
BAKSMALI_JAR_PATH = "/Users/rabbit/tools/baksmali-2.2.7.jar"
SMALI_JAR_PATH = "/Users/rabbit/tools/smali-2.2.7.jar"

Copy paste this script in your terminal and restart your terminal. This is a shortcut function which would get added to `.bash_profile` and you would get it handy.

```
    echo "BAKSMALI_JAR_PATH="$BAKSMALI_JAR_PATH >> ~/.bash_profile
    echo "SMALI_JAR_PATH="$SMALI_JAR_PATH >> ~/.bash_profile
    echo >>
    function odextodex() {
       odex_file_name=$1
       deassembled_file=${odex_file_name%.odex}
       java -jar $BAKSMALI_JAR_PATH d $1 -o $deassembled_file
       java -jar $SMALI_JAR_PATH ass $deassembled_file -o $deassembled_file.dex
       rm -rf $deassembled_file
    }
```

After doing this type `odextodex` filename.odex - you should see filename.jar file in your current directory.